# Try Catch Not Working - Why?

Tags: java

In the below code, I am trying to implement a try-catch on an input. This works as a standalone, when the `while` loop isn't in use. That doesn't achieve what I'm trying to do, so I tried the loop. This then creates an infinite loop, which I don't really understand why.

```
public static void AllIn() {
    System.out.println("Please select your menu option: ");
    while(true) {
        try {
            MenuSelect = Input.nextInt();           
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("That's not a valid number!");
        }
    }

 }
```

Another solution I thought might work was calling this method through another method in the `catch` block. This created a loop that ended in a `StackOverflowError` being returned. Does anyone have a suggestion for how to get this to work?

My variables that I'm working with for this are:

```
private static Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in); 
private static int MenuSelect;
```

And yes, I am aware that I shouldn't be using private statics to do this, but I couldn't really think of an alternative.

Comment: From the javadoc: **If the translation is successful**, the scanner advances past the input that matched. (emphasis mine). Since the translation, in your case, is not successful, the scanner does not advance, and thus tries to read the exact same thing the next time you call it. Note that your code violates the Jaa naming conventions. Variables start with a lowercase letter in Java

Comment: Thank you, I've a tendency to forget that, I appreciate the reminder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your while loop does not have any `break` or `return` in it, so the only way it can finish is if its condition is `false`. But its condition is `true` so it can't be false. This creates an infinite loop.

There's another reason as well. When the scanner reads an invalid int, it does not go past those characters. This means that the next time the scanner tries to read it, the invalid int is still there and it will try to read that, which it fails at, and this goes on and on.

One solution is to `break` if the input is alright, and also consume the int if it fails:

```
System.out.println("Please select your menu option: ");
while(true) {
    try {
        MenuSelect = Input.nextInt();   
        break;        
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("That's not a valid number!");
        Input.nextLine(); // consumes the invalid int.
    }
}
// do stuff with the input here...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void AllIn() {
    System.out.println("Please select your menu option: ");
    while(true) {
        try {
            MenuSelect = Input.nextInt();           
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("That's not a valid number!");
            // added this line to make Scanner omit last newline
            Input.nextLine();
        }
    }

 }
```